# Bourbon-Neat column to top of container

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, bourbon

I have the following in my CSS:

```
body {
   @include outer-container; 
   color: $Dark-Blue;
   background-color: $Light-Blue;
 }

.main{
   @include span-columns(12);
   background-color: $White;
 }
```

There is a small gap at the top of the .main area -is there any way of getting it to extend all the way to the top of the viewing area?  I've looked for info on the neat.bourbon.io site (also looked at the w3schools.com site) but I don't think I'm asking the right question, so not sure how to search...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about make your body as .wrapper instead.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main"></div>
</div>
```

if it's not working, try adding a reset css before everything else? the code have no issues, most likely you didn't have these:

```
body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
```